# Convert a Non Eulerian Path Into a Eulerian Path By Adding Double/Parallel Edges

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

A Eulerian path in graph theory is a path that traverses every edge of the graph **exactly** once.

Of course a Eulerian path doesn't always exist for a given graph.

What I'm trying to do is strategically add the least number of parallel edges i.e. basically traversing some edges twice.

So all in all the question becomes how to traverse a graph where every edge is traversed at least once but not more than twice.

There can be multiple paths between the same two nodes even before adding any parallel edges.

Comment: The good man was called Euler, not Eular.

Comment: Is your graph guaranteed to be *connected*?

Answer (score 1):

A graph has an Eulerian path [if, and only when](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Properties),

> exactly zero or two vertices have odd degree, and all of its vertices with nonzero degree belong to a single connected component

Because adding an edge always increases the sum of the degrees with 2, it is not possible to have an odd number of vertices that have odd degree.

It is of course not possible to solve the problem when the graph has multiple components with edges, as you would need to add edges between nodes that are not connected by a path, and so they would not be *parallel* edges. Secondly, completely isolated vertices (with degree 0) play no role in this problem, so we can just ignore them and assume the graph is connected.

The task remains to ensure the graph has at most 2 vertices with an odd degree.

If this is not the case, we should pair all vertices with odd degree such that the sum of the pairs distances is minimized. This is a [minimum cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut) problem where the *weights* of that problem are the shortest path lengths. Once this pairing is done, the problem is solved:

Add parallel edges along the shortest paths that link two vertices in a pair (except the last pair, because one pair of odd degrees is allowed). Adding these parallel edges will only change the *parity* of the two end vertices of that path.

### Addendum

Someone commented that edges could be shared by two paths coming out of the minimum cut algorithm, leading to the addition of 2 parallel edges between the same pair of vertices. But this will not occur. If there would be four vertices which would be paired in such a way that the two paths would share an edge, we could find two paths without that shared edge by pairing those four vertices differently.

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution was very useful to me, however I don't fully understand the part of _"This [meant: finding pairing with minimized sum] is a minimum cut problem"_. We need to find optimal (with minimized sum) pairing in a complete graph, hence obviously we cannot use algorithms based on source and sink (since we don't know which nodes are sources and which are sinks). And having look into Without terminal nodes section of that Wikipedia page, it seems that Stoer-Wagner algorithm does not necessarily have to produce pairing or am I overlooking something?